# Sort an array from lower to higher

Tags: php, arrays

i've created multiple arrays just like this one:

```
<?php
    $student1 = array("name" => "dean", "score" => "10", "time" => "5");
?>
```

i've created 15 arrays just like the one above but with different values, after this i've created an array where i store the 15 arrays previously created just like this

```
<?php 
    $class = array($student1,$student2,....)
?>
```

now im asked to order `$class` from lower to higher depending on the score of the student

any help?

Comment: I don't understand why you make an array for each student, just to merge them to a single different array.

Answer (score 0):

First, just make the combined array all at once instead of making a separate array per student.

Now, you just need to sort `$class` depending on `score` using [usort](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php).

Then, loop through the array and output the information to the page (based on your comment `i just need to show the names and scores with the sort`)

```
$class = array(
    array("name" => "dean", "score" => "10", "time" => "5"),
    array("name" => "student2", "score" => "5", "time" => "5"),
    array("name" => "student3", "score" => "8", "time" => "5")
);

usort($class, function($a, $b) {
    return $b['score'] - $a['score'];
});

//loop through the values to display
foreach($class as $key => $value) {
    
    //array keys start at 0, so add 1 to get the position on the leaderboard
    $position = $key + 1;

    echo "{$position}: {$value['name']} ({$value['score']})<br>";
}
```

Output

```
1: dean (10)
2: student3 (8)
3: student2 (5)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but when i put that code into mine, it doesn't do anything, the page shows blank, im kinda new to php. ill copy my code below:

Comment: $class = array(

array("nome" => "Diogo", "score" => "10
array("nome" => "Joana", "score" => "100", "time" => "6" ),
array("nome" => "Diogo", "score" => "275", "time" => "4" ),
array("nome" => "Francisco", "score" => "300", "time" => "9" ),
);

usort($class, function($a,$b){
 return $a['score'] - $b['score'];
});  

i've changed the code to portuguese that the logic is the same

Comment: @DiogoPereira That's because I don't know how you want to actually handle the data or display it. All my code does is _sort_ it. It won't show anything on the page without you doing something additional.

Comment: i just need to show the names and scores with the sort, and then show the top 3, its like a leaderboard

Comment: for example :

1: Dean: 900
2:Jean:300
3: John: 500

Comment: and after that show the remain students with their scores

Comment: @DiogoPereira Output wasn't really a part of your question, but I updated my answer regardless. Try the new code, and note the change I made in the `usort` function to make it descending instead of ascending score.

Comment: Thank you so much, your saving lifes here xD, one more question, how would u show the only the top 3 below the list of students?

Comment: @DiogoPereira You can just do the same loop again but add `if($position > 3) continue;` right above the `echo`.

Comment: it works amazingly, now i need to add some options, if there is a draw in terms of score the fastest time wins, if there is draw in score and time, then i need to order alphabetically

Comment: @DiogoPereira This is getting way out of the realm of your original question, you should post a new question for this.

Answer (score 0):

```
$student1 = array("name" => "dean", "score" => "10", "time" => "5");

$students = array(
      "Student1" => array("name" => "dean", "score" => "10", "time" => "5"),
      "Student2" => array());

foreach($students as $item) {
       sort($item[1]);
}
```

I think the best solution is by making a 2D-array for the $class, and looping through it.

Comment: This doesn't work. `$item[1]` doesn't refer to anything, and even if it did, it couldn't sort the `$students` array at all.